# How can I make subscribe and unsubscribe button with Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two buttons `subscribe and unsubscribe` I need when the user click on `subscribe` change the button to `unsubscribe` real-time:

I do `subscribe` one but I don't know how can I switch to `unsubscribe`

```
public function subscribe()
{
    Subscribe::firstOrCreate([
        'user_id' =>  user()->id,
        'store_id' => $this->store->id,
    ]);
    
}
```

HTML

```
 <button wire:click="subscribe" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="far fa-heart text-danger h4 pt-2"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a public (computed) property on the component that contains whatever logic you need to determine whether the user is subscribed:

```php
public function getIsSubscribedProperty()
{
    // return true or false from here
}
```

then you can wrap your buttons in a blade 'if':

```html
@if($isSubscribed)

<button wire:click="unsubscribe" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="far fa-times-circle text-danger h4 pt-2"></i>
</button>

@else

<button wire:click="subscribe" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="far fa-heart text-danger h4 pt-2"></i>
</button>

@endif
```

Comment: thank you so much do it like you said. pls can you check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714699/update-on-change-with-livewire