# update on change with livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have this input type number for `qty`:

[image]

The html code:

```
<span class="qty-btn minus-btn" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()">
    <i class="fal fa-minus-circle"></i>
</span>

<input
    wire:model.lazy="quantity"
    wire:change="updateQuantity({{ $product->id }})"
    type="number"
    class="input-text qty text"
    title="Qty" inputmode="numeric"
    step="1" min="1" max="" lang="en"
>

<span class="qty-btn plus-btn" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()">
    <i class="fal fa-plus-circle"></i>
</span>
```

I need when I click on any button `stepDown` or `stepUp` update the `qty`

my Livewire component:

```
class CartQtySection extends Component
{
    public $product;
    public $quantity;

    public function mount($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->quantity = $product->pivot->quantity;
    }

    public function updateQuantity($id)
    {
        user()->cart()->updateExistingPivot($id, [
        'quantity' => $this->quantity,
        ]);

        $this->emit('quantityUpdated');
    }
}
```

Comment: don't user javascript `onclick` function as  u r using livewaire `stepDown()` this function u can write in livewire itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `wire:click`

```php
<span class="qty-btn minus-btn" wire:click="stepDown({{ $product->id }})">
    <i class="fal fa-minus-circle"></i>
</span>


<span class="qty-btn plus-btn" wire:click="stepUp({{ $product->id }})">
    <i class="fal fa-plus-circle"></i>
</span>
```

**in Compoenent**

```php
<?php

class CartQtySection extends Component
{
    public $product;
    public $quantity;

    public function mount($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->quantity = $product->pivot->quantity;
    }

    public function updateQuantity($id)
    {
        user()->cart()->updateExistingPivot($id, [
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
        ]);

        $this->emit('quantityUpdated');
    }

    public function stepDown($id)
    {
        $this->quantity++;
        $this->updateQuantity($id)
    }
    public function stepUp($id)
    {
        $this->quantity--;
        $this->updateQuantity($id)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't :(

Comment: @akin check now

Comment: Cool thanks worked, but how can I update the qty when click on any function ? I need to update the qty also by updateQuantity function

Comment: @akin check now